# .NET HttpWebRequest HTTPS Error

Tags: c#, .net, https, httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

Hello I'm trying to fetch data from a https web (i'm not behind firewall or proxy) however even accepting all certificates it keeps throwing `System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.SecureChannelFailure` with the message shown: Cancelled the request: Unable to create a secure SSL/TLS channel
... i've looked everywhere so you guys are my last chance.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                RemoteCertificateValidationCallback ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://miyoigo.yoigo.com");
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: can you hit the same url successfully with a browser?

Comment: yes i usually do by web browser but wanna do it programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem looking at:
[How do you get a System.Web.HttpWebRequest object to use SSL 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169222/how-do-you-get-a-system-web-httpwebrequest-object-to-use-ssl-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

try printing the InnerException property of the WebException, should provide a particular reason the negot failed

```
Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception");
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(e.InnerException.StackTrace, e.InnerException.Message));
```

Comment: The Message tells me is something like (translated): Cancelled the request: Unable to create a secure SSL/TLS channel

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine for me exactly as you have it.  My guess is that you've got something network related going on.  Are you behind a proxy or firewall?  Like Ray said in his comment, try hitting that URL from a browser.

Comment: i'm connected directly to the router